# Transition height of without using max-height

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to transition the height of a `div` without using `max-height` because the `.block-content` has a variable height. I got it working using `max-height` but when the content got larger than the `max-height` it didn't show it properly. I also tried using `max-height: 9999999px` but that also fail.

I have something like this [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/RpmsPc9rB2GDmtJ0M9HT/) where when I click on the `.block-header` the `.block-content` shows.

What I want is to transition the `.block-content` so that it looks like it slides in from the `.block-header`.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: sorry, not clear what you want.

Comment: You can use slide toggle http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_slide_toggle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6kx4hhqn/). Please check it clearly and let me know...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".block-header").click(function(){
        $(".block-content").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```